# Multiple IIF conditions in SSRS doesn't work

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have some trouble getting an IIF statement to work in SSRS. 
My goal is to add different actions to a field in my report, based on the value in the field **Beschikbare_datum.Value**. The statement actually works, but when I add the last IIF part, the rest of actions don't work anymore except for the last defined action. Any help / tips would be greatly appreciated.

My statement looks like this:

```
=IIF(Fields!Beschikbare_datum.Value =
"Beschikbaar","javascript:void(window.open('http://ncoi-synergy/synergytest/docs/WflRequest.aspx?BCAction=0&Type=3161&StartDate="&Fields!StartDate.Value & "','_blank'))",

IIF(Fields!Beschikbare_datum.Value = "(Voorlopig) Ingepland","MailTo:" & "aprins@ncoi.nl"  & "?Subject=" & "Aanpassing beschikbaarheid surveilleren "  & Fields!ExamenDatum.Value,

IIF(Fields!Beschikbare_datum.Value = "Beschikbaarheid reeds opgegeven","MailTo:" & "aprins@ncoi.nl"  & "?Subject=" & "Aanpassing beschikbaarheid surveilleren "  & Fields!ExamenDatum.Value, 

IIF(Fields!Beschikbare_datum.Value = "Uren / reiskosten declareren", "javascript:void(window.open('http://ogas01/synergyenterprise/docs/WflRequest.aspx?Mode=1&ID=%7b"& Fields!Declaratie_verzoek.Value.ToString & "%7d&BCAction=1','_blank'))"
    ,""))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using switch statement:

```
=Switch(
Fields!Beschikbare_datum.Value="Beschikbaar",
  "javascript:void(window.open('http://ncoi-synergy/synergytest/docs/WflRequest.aspx?BCAction=0&Type=3161&StartDate="&Fields!StartDate.Value & "','_blank'))",

Fields!Beschikbare_datum.Value="(Voorlopig) Ingepland",
  "MailTo:" & "aprins@ncoi.nl"  & "?Subject=" & "Aanpassing beschikbaarheid surveilleren "  & Fields!ExamenDatum.Value,

Fields!Beschikbare_datum.Value="Beschikbaarheid reeds opgegeven",
  "MailTo:" & "aprins@ncoi.nl"  & "?Subject=" & "Aanpassing beschikbaarheid surveilleren "  & Fields!ExamenDatum.Value,

Fields!Beschikbare_datum.Value = "Uren / reiskosten declareren",
  "javascript:void(window.open('http://ogas01/synergyenterprise/docs/WflRequest.aspx?Mode=1&ID=%7b"& Fields!Declaratie_verzoek.Value.ToString & "%7d&BCAction=1','_blank'))",

true,""
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't change the situation. Only the last option works, the first 3 options still don't result in the defined action.

Comment: Is the JS action not working or the switch statement is returning the wrong JS action?. Check if the logic flow is the correct. If the the Switch is returning the right value for the given case the problem is you have to encode your urls.

Comment: The JS action is not working, also the Mailto action isn't working. If I take out the last statement, the other 3 result into the right defined actions, so the JS and the Mailto action result to my browser and mailapplication opening. So I guess the URL's are correct, but something in the complete string is resulting in this problem.

Comment: It seems you have to encode the URL. Check [this](http://capstonebi.blogspot.com.co/2010/04/url-encoding-in-reporting-services.html)